# "No graphics environment found" while X11 is running

Tags: java, unix, awt, solaris, headless

My code that was generating PI charts in our Solaris system was working fine earlier, but somehow now the Java is exiting with an Exception saying "No graphics environment found", even if X11 is running. I am sure that no code was changed.  What are some possible issues in terms of Unix?

Our system admin has provided the following details from the Solaris server:

```
$:/root# ps -ef | grep -i Xsun
root 25920 25246   0 10:34:24 pts/3       0:00 grep -i Xsun
root 18528  4999   0   Jan 01 ?           0:00 /usr/openwin/bin/Xsun :0 +nkeyboard +nmouse -dev vfb
```

Is there anything else I should look for?

This is what the script says:

```
#!/bin/sh 
# Copyright 2002, 2003 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved. 
# Use is subject to license terms. 

# Split off Server Number 
ServerNumber=\`echo $1 |grep ":"\` 
if [ "$ServerNumber" ] then shift fi
exec /usr/openwin/bin/Xsun $ServerNumber +nkeyboard +nmouse -dev vfb $*
```

Comment: Do you have the `DISPLAY` environment variable set?

Comment: This is what the script says

Comment: Please add that to your question. Properly formatted. This is not readable.

Comment: ``#!/bin/sh   

 # Copyright 2002, 2003 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.   
 # Use is subject to license terms.   
     
 # Split off Server Number   
  ServerNumber=\`echo $1 |grep ":"\`   
   
  if [ "$ServerNumber" ]   
  then   
  shift   
  fi   
   
  exec /usr/openwin/bin/Xsun $ServerNumber +nkeyboard +nmouse -dev vfb $*     
``

Comment: Display variable is set, we are passing :0

Comment: DISPALY variable is set. System.getProperty("os.name") is returning SunOS.  (String) java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged
  (new sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction
   ("java.awt.graphicsenv", null)) is returning sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment . Still facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the keyword that you put in this question I noticed "headless": does it mean that you've installed a headless jre? That could be the reason: the headless jre does not contain required jars to create visual elements (windows, widgets etc)

Comment: Is there any specific lib file that I need to verify?